# jquery toggle menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

Im trying to achieve a css jquery toggle menu, but it doesn't function
these are the codes im using

CSS:

```
#submenu  ul{
display:none;
} 

#submenu ul li {
text-align: right;
display: block;
}

.bnt {
display: block;
color:#fff;
font-size: 15px;
text-align: right;
cursor: pointer;
}

.bnt:before {
content:"menu";
}
```

and the JS

```
<script>
$('.bnt').click(function () {
   $('#submenu ul').toggle();
})
</script>
```

is there any error on these codes?

Comment: Don't you have html, if please post here

Comment: may be you need to wrap your code in ready handler...where are you loading script, in head? If yes, just load that before closing body..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you need to wrap your code in ready handler and Make sure you have loaded the jQuery before your Script start or in the `<head>....</head>` section:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bnt').click(function () {
      $('#submenu ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/apa26qra/)**